# How does GFortran handle stride=1 arrays?

Tags: performance, fortran, compiler-construction, gfortran

When arrays have `stride` equal to 1 (a very common case), it seems that code compiled for the generic case (any nonzero `stride`) will often be suboptimal.

On the other hand, creating multiple versions of compiled functions and subroutines when some of the arguments are `stride=1` scales ***exponentially*** with the number of arguments that are arrays.

What is the approach taken by GFortran here?

Comment: Presumably this is for dummy array arguments, and do you care about the CONTIGUOUS attribute?

Comment: @francescalus If I'm not mistaken, a multidimensional array can be `stride=1` and not be `CONTIGUOUS`. In any case, the compiler generally cannot know what kind of arrays may be passed to a subroutine. How does it prepare for the ***exponential*** number of possibilities?

Comment: Something with stride 1 is contiguous, but the CONTIGUOUS attribute is stronger: it makes the object _simply_ contiguous. Is that something someone answering should address?

Comment: @francescalus I never used F2008, but as I understand, an NxN matrix with leading dimension > N will not be contiguous, but each of its columns may be contiguous (stride=1). I don't think an answer needs to address the CONTIGUOUS tag.

Comment: [Hi @bobcat, here is one reply from gfortran developers https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.fortran/c/jcUiMfc4xi0/m/lZtYy3HQAgAJ It may be useful to ask the question also in that forum]

Comment: @roygvib Thanks. I refocused the question on GFortran to make it more answerable, if any GFortran experts want to write up an answer.